# Unable to run in production mode on heroku server

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I have an application which is deployed on heroku and for some reasons I want to enable web console there.
This is the setup details:
In Gemfile

```
ruby '2.3.0'

rails 4.2

web console 3.3.0
```

in Application.rb

```
config.web_console.development_only = false
 config.web_console.whitelisted_ips = [MY IP ADDRESS]
```

When I tried to run on local with production env it is working fine even when I add other machine IP address(connected via LAN) and try to access the web app installed on my machine it seems working(when I remove their IP address then it is not showing any console on web pages) so I can say config.web_console.whiltelisted_ips configuration is working.

but when I add my external IP address(public IP address) in whitelisted ips and push to heroku then I am unable to see web console there.

always sees some random ips there in console like this:

```
Cannot render console from 10.63.146.94! Allowed networks: 103.15.67.226, 174.129.192.200, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255, ::1
```

and this '10.63.146.94!' change always.

I am not sure where I am missing something or there are some error in gem?

Answer (score 0):

The `10.*` range of IPs is private, meaning the code running the web console is seeing another heroku machine as the source.  This is usually what happens if the code is not taking into account headers like `X-Forwarded-For`.

You might find it easier to use the web console that heroku provide.